# Unexpected constructor call on a class that extends Array

Tags: javascript

Please don't worry about what this code is for; it's a simplification I pulled out of a debugging session.

I expected `f` to behave like an `Array`, but if you run that code under a debugger (I've tested node and Chrome) you'll see that, for some reason I can't explain, the constructor in the `wtf` class is called during the execution of `u`.  And to make things weirder, `ghostArg` appears with the value of `4`.  Can you explain what's going on?

```js
class wtf extends Array {
  constructor(ghostArg){
    super();
    if(ghostArg){
      this.push(...ghostArg);
    }
  }
}

const f = new wtf();

f.push({'n':1});
f.push({'n':0});
f.push({'n':3});
f.push({'n':7});

const u = x => x.map(e=>e.n);
console.log(u(f)); // I expected to see [1,0,3,7] out of here
```

Comment: I’d avoid extending `Array` with an incompatible constructor and use a static method instead.

Comment: You have to add [Symbol.species](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/species) to the class to make it work as intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can you explain what's going on?

[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) creates a new array, `new Array(n)`, where `n` is the length of the array on which `map` was called. In your case, that length (`n`) is `4`.

Now, consider the behavior of your constructor when taking `4` as an argument:

```js
if(4){               //if(ghostArg){
  this.push(...4);   //  this.push(...ghostArg);
}                    //}
```

`4` is not iterable, therefore `...4` will throw an error stating as much:

> "TypeError: ghostArg is not iterable"